# Generic test automation framework for Python

Tags: python, testing, frameworks, automated-tests

I'm working as a system administrator/infrastructure engineer, and sometimes I am wasting my time on checking if everything working properly after infrastructure changes. I want to write some tests, such as:

- Download some CSS/JavaScript code from a website
- Login to website
- Upload some file and try to download it
- Login to a server and execute some script
- And so on.

Most unit testing frameworks focused on unit testing and code coverage, but all I need is just a configurable runner for my tests with nice reporting and may be additional modules for ease of writing HTTP tests. Possibility to use this tool for stress-testing would be an advantage.

I've found many names (testoob, functest, robotframework, py.test, etc.), but I don't know what to choose.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Robot Framework has many nice libraries that would definitely help you - so you don't have to reinvent the wheel. For example, Robot Framework integrates with [the Selenium web testing tool](http://code.google.com/p/robotframework-seleniumlibrary/).

I think that from the tools that you mentioned Robot Framework is the most active project - py.test seems to be active also.

One thing that you should notice is that Robot tests are not written in Python directly, but they use a simple text based syntax. You can of course access Robots libraries from Python code if you want to or create your own robot library in Python code.

[DISCLAIMER: I am a member of the team that is developing Robot Framework]

Answer (score 1):

I develop an open-source framework (part of [Pycopia](http://code.google.com/p/pycopia/)) that does exactly this. It's not complete yet (still working on the web UI), but it's usable to run real tests and get emailed reports. You write tests in Python, but it also manages test cases, test results, and equipment inventory.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look. But it seems to be problematic, due to lack of documentation. :(

Comment: @rvs Yes, I'm sorry, you are right about that. :-( I'm working on it...